# Select The data from Dynamic Dropdown in Macro file

Tags: vba

I am working on Macro excel file in which multiple dynamic dropdowns are there for every column.
I have 2 excel file ,one is input file and another one which I need to update on the basis of requirements.
I need to pick value one by one from input file and then check it from dropdown values of excel-2.
If that value doesn't exist in dropdown then bot needs to skip the entire row and move to next one.

I am not able to understand that how to fix it.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.
Nidhi

Comment: There's absolutely no way we can help without specific information (including code) and a description of the exact problem you're having with this setup.

Comment: It looks like you are new here. Please read this blog post on how to ask a question that will get good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask